# Georeferenced bitmaps

Tags: export, image, geography

The command `Export["filename.jpg", graphic]` will export the graphic object `graphic` to the file `filename.jpg` in versions > 8 (at least). TIFF's are also used.  I am interested in georeferenced bitmaps which can be used with various GIS's, and the default export command does not produce appropriate files.

Has anybody found a way of exporting graphics in such a way that they are georeferenced?

Comment: These are the geospatial formats supported (usually partially) by Mathematica http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/GeospatialFormats.html

Comment: @belisarius: Many thanks!  I was aware of this link.  The GeoTIFF that is mentioned has many (some ...) fine examples for Import[], but few for output.  My interest is exclusive to Export[].  If MMA 9.0 can't Export[] georeferenced files, then it is great to know, so's we can put in a feature request for 10.0 (11.0 ...).